# Laravel,Ajax,Jquery Plugin image upload,preview, convert to thumbnails and display

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/It8w9.png)preview uploaded images after upload.and to show the image on the form.Want to achieve this with help of jquery image upload with Laravel framework. help is appreciated.

**@Simon I have implemented ur code.its working,but one image is shown in view and i want to show all three images,which are selected.Plz help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvmAR.png)**

Answer (score 1):

if you using the standard file input type and say your using a moderish browser etc then you could try the following.

```js
$('#addImage').on('change', function(evt) {
  var selectedImage = evt.currentTarget.files[0];
  var imageWrapper = document.querySelector('.image-wrapper');
  var theImage = document.createElement('img');
  imageWrapper.innerHTML = '';
 
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.png|.bmp)$/;
  if (regex.test(selectedImage.name.toLowerCase())) {
    if (typeof(FileReader) != 'undefined') {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
          theImage.id = 'new-selected-image';
          theImage.src = e.target.result;
          imageWrapper.appendChild(theImage);
        }
        //
      reader.readAsDataURL(selectedImage);
    } else {
      //-- Let the user knwo they cannot peform this as browser out of date
      console.log('browser support issue');
    }
  } else {
    //-- no image so let the user knwo we need one...
    $(this).prop('value', null);
    console.log('please select and image file');
  }

});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 25px;
}

.image-wrapper {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px #ddd solid;
  height auto;
  width: 200px;
}

.image-wrapper img {
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="file" id="addImage" />
</div>
<div class="image-wrapper">
  
</div>
```

also viewable on [codepen Exmaple](http://codepen.io/simondavies/pen/dXkPVy)